# How "press" a table in SAS

Tags: merge, sas

This is my example. In `SAS` I have a table where in `column1` there are `n` variables, and every variable is repeated some times. In `column2` there are or OK or KO.
I want to generate a synthetic table where every variable is repeated only one time (so I'll have only `n` records) and where in `column2` there is OK, if in the first table ALL the values of `column2` referred to `variableK` is OK and KO if even only one of the values of `column2` referred to variableK is KO.

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Please post some sample data and what you've tried. As your question stands it does not SO standards.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a Data Step and the BY statement.

First sort you data by `column1`

```
proc sort data=have out=want
by column1;
run;
```

Then filter the table as you require

```
data want;
set want;
by column1;
format variableK $2.;
retain variableK;

if first.column1 then
   variableK = "OK";

if column2 = "KO" then
   variableK = "KO";

if last.column2 then
   output;
run;
```

`RETAIN` tells SAS to keep the value of `variableK` between records.

`first.column1` is a flag that lets us know when we are at the start of a new value in `column1`.  Here we set `variableK` to OK.

Then we check to see if `column2` is `='KO'` and set `variableK` accordingly.

Finally `last.column1` tells us when we are at the end of a value in `column1`.  We use the `OUTPUT` statement to explicitly tell SAS to only output that record.